# Vba set cells are equal to cells from another worksheet

Tags: vba

I want to write macro which sets cells in  worksheets "Section_errors" and   "Elemant_errors" is equal to cells in "ICS Analysis"  worksheet. All data exists in "ICS Analysis" . I try the code below, but it doesnot work and any error doesnot appear. What can be a reason? I tryied also simple copy-paste, it operates, but it takes too much time

```
 Sub copy_id()
Dim i As Integer
Dim lastrow As Integer

lastrow = Worksheets("ICS Analysis").Cells(Worksheets("ICS Analysis").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastrow

Worksheets("Element_errors").Cells(i, 73).Value = Worksheets("ICS Analysis").Cells(i, 3).Value
Worksheets("Section_errors").Cells(i, 10).Value = Worksheets("ICS Analysis").Cells(i, 3).Value
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Move your `lastrow = Worksheets....` line above your `For` line,

Comment: You have not calculated lastrow and it will never go inside the for loop, The code should be : 1st `lastrow = Worksheets("ICS Analysis").Cells(Worksheets("ICS Analysis").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` then `For i = 1 To lastrow`

Comment: I Changed it but Problem still remains(

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't a very informative description of the problem.

Comment: I don't see anything else wrong with the code.  As John said, we'll need more info otherwise we're just guessing...  You have values in ICS Analysis (Column C)?  And your checking Element_errors (Column BU), and Section_errors (Column J) for copied values?  Only other thing to check is to make sure you are actually calling copy_id.

Answer (score 0):

**The solution according to me is:**

```
Sub copy_id()
Dim i As Integer
Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = Worksheets("ICS Analysis").Cells(Worksheets("ICS Analysis").Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To lastrow
Worksheets("Element_errors").Cells(i, 73).Value = Worksheets("ICS Analysis").Cells(i,3).Value
Worksheets("Section_errors").Cells(i, 10).Value = Worksheets("ICS Analysis").Cells(i,3).Value
Next i
End Sub
```

The change is the location of the definition of the variable **lastrow**.

You see, in the earlier version, the **lastrow** was getting a value 1 before entering the loop and thus the loop was not running.

Hence no data.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I tryed it, but it does not work. Its strange, since the macro is so easy.(

Comment: I tried the same code, just now on my system. And its working just fine....

Comment: it runs but i dont see the numbers in Worksheets("Section_errors").Cells(i, 10) and Worksheets("Element_errors").Cells(i, 73). Maybe i Need to add something?